# Sorting directory contents (including hidden files) by name in the shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sorting, awk

Is there a nice way to sort directory contents (including hidden files) in the shell? Basically i'd like to be able to `ls` directories just its done in my GUI file manager. In a typical directory, the output is as such:

> .a_hidden_dir
>
> .b_hidden_dir
>
> .c_hidden_dir
>
> a_dir
>
> b_dir
>
> c_dir
>
> .a_hidden_file
>
> .b_hidden_file
>
> .c_hidden_file
>
> a_file
>
> b_file
>
> c_file

Of course `ls` has the `--group-directories-first` option, but this only gets us part of the way there as `sort` ignores the leading `.`, it does not sort hidden files to the top.

I'd like to be able to sort output from `ls`, `find`, or other list of paths in such a way. Does anyone know a good way to do this - maybe a `sort -k` *KEYDEF*?

Right now I'm doing something like this (it assumes directory names have a slash append to them):

```
pathsort(){
    input=$(cat)
    (
        awk '/^\..+\/$/' <<<"$input" | sort
        awk '/^[^.].+\/$/' <<<"$input" | sort
        awk '/^\..+[^/]$/' <<<"$input" | sort
        awk '/^[^.].+[^/]$/' <<<"$input" | sort
    ) | sed 's/\/$//'
}

\ls -Ap | pathsort
```

The above code gets the job done, but it is far from ideal. Please tell me there is a better way...

Comment: Post the output you expect.

Comment: ls -la isn't working?

Comment: Sample input can be obtained from running `\ls -Ap`. Expected sample output is in the first quoted block of text above (starting with .a_hidden_dir). `ls -la` "works" of course, but I am trying to get the output sorted, with hidden stuff at the top, as it is in a file manager. I want it ordered hidden directories, directories, hidden files, files.

Comment: Have you tried setting LANG=C in the environment so that the sort is done in C order, with the names with leading dots appearing before most other names.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ahh thank you, that was so simple! I have used LC_ALL=C with `sort` for reproducible builds before but didn't know about LANG=C. `LANG=C \ls -A --group-directories-first` was exactly what I needed... And here I was jerry rigging some terrible contraption. Thanks again!

Comment: You could use `LC_ALL` instead of, or as well as, `LANG` with both `ls` and `sort`.  You should also be able to use `LC_COLLATE` too; that's the most precise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) proposed a simple and functional solution in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30023780/sorting-directory-contents-including-hidden-files-by-name-in-the-shell?noredirect=1#comment48165651_30023780): set the local environment variable `LANG=C`. On my system, the default `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` results in undesirable pathname sorting characteristics. The C is apparently in reference to bytewise character sorting with an ASCII charset. The result of setting `LANG=C` is such that 'dotfiles' (to include directories) are sorted to the top. It may be useful to note that `LC_ALL=C` may be used as well, as `LC_ALL` is a superset of `LANG` and other `LC_*` variables. All in all, setting the locale to C for sorting commands is strongly advised if you'd like a consistent sorting experience.

Here is the final solution to the desired pathname sorting hierarchy (dotfile dirs > normal dirs > dotfile files > normal files):

```
LC_ALL=C ls -A --group-directories-first
```

*Note: this includes symlinks to files and directories as well*

Similarly for sorting any other source of pathname output:

```
findtool | LC_ALL=C sort
```

Answer (score 0):

Funnily, I think sorting the directories is simplest:

```
ls -1d .*/; ls -1d */
```

Files are harder to separate from the directories, you need to use find:

```
(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '.*' -printf '%P\n' | sort); (find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -name '.*' -printf '%P\n' | sort)
```

Put the whole thing together:

```
alias lss="
    ls -1d .*/;   # Hidden directories
    ls -1d */;    # Normal directories
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '.*' -printf '%P\n' | sort;
                  # Hidden files
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -name '.*' -printf '%P\n' | sort
                  # Normal files
"
```

One caveat: There are other items that this will miss, like links and devices.

Comment: Your lsd looks good. I had done something very similar to the second example with lsd `(find -L -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '.*' -printf '%P\n' | sort; find -L -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d ! -name '.*' -printf '%P\n' | sort)` and lsf `(find -L -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '.*' -printf '%P\n' | sort; find -L -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name '.*' -printf '%P\n' | sort)`. The `-L` will catch links to dirs/files. I wanted to be able to sort other output also... turns out this was making something really complicated out of nothing. You can get the desired sorting via `LC_ALL=C \ls -A --g`. :P

Comment: Yes, maybe you should answer your own question with the update and mark it answered. That way other people that might have a similar question will see your answer.